# How to edit text in powerpoint slide show?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

Sometimes while giving a power point presentation to our board, they tend to suggest corrections on slides & tell us to update.

What I do is to note them & exit the slideshow, update the slide & then goto full screen mode again.

```
Is there a way to edit my slide text when its opened as 
a powerpoint show (full screen) ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple monitors attached (or a projector and a monitor), then PP 2010 opens the show in fullscreen on one and the "edit screen" on the other. You can freely edit on the second screen, everything you change is immediately reflected on the other screen in the show.

Comment: Thanks thats awesome! Any workaround for single monitors?

Comment: None that I'm aware of, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have one monitor and need to edit something on a slide, press Alt+TAB to highlight the open instance of PowerPoint (it should be the next choice) then let go the alt key.  The PowerPoint normal view window is now active ... do your edits, then press Alt+Tab once to return to the running slide show.  With your changes in place.